# Can't access mysql table, get a message that it has crashed

Tags: mysql

I have a a mysql table that I can't access, I get the following error

```
ERROR 1194 (HY000): Table 'menu_config' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

How do I go about in fixing this? And will all my data be lost?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=repair+mysql+table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following SQL statement:

```
REPAIR TABLE 'menu_config'
```

Answer (score 0):

O E is correct, `REPAIR TABLE 'menu_config'` should do it. If you don't have direct access to the server via a console, phpMyAdmin also has a "repair table" option which should do the trick.